# Direct Messaging on a "Public" Server in Python

Tags: python, server, instant-messaging

I'm trying to send a message to a specific individual on a public Socket-based Server using python.

Say Client 1, Client 2, Client 3 and Client 4 are all on the same chatroom server and Client 1 wants to send a message directly to Client 3 without Client 2 and Client 4 seeing it. How can I relay the message from Client 1 to Client 3 using the socket library? The only way I know how to transfer a message is by using socket.sendall(), and that clearly won't hide the message from Client 2 and Client 4.

I'm also trying to make multiple chatrooms within the server but that is a problem for a later time (ex.: clients 1,2,3 want to chat solely amongst themselves without having to look at the globalchat. How can I generate a chatroom with password access?).

Here is my code for the private messaging/regular messaging relay on the server side. (it's based off of a public template, I intend to alter it further later). Under the elif is the private "sending" of the message.

```
clientList = {
1:Client1
2:Client2
3:Client3
4:Client4

#later on I will make the code that separates the client's servername from a /w (name) (message). My thought process is that by comparing the typed name to the dictionary it should send a message to the user who matches - if there is no comparison, an error would pop up and say "this user is not active on the server. Please try again.". For now, I have code that detects "/w" at the start of a string, which you can find below.
}

def client_handler(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('You are now connected to the replay server... Type BYE to stop'))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        message = data.decode('utf-8')
        if message == 'BYE':
            break
        elif message == Regex.IsMatch(str,"^/w "):
          reply = f'Server: {message}' # <<<PRIVATE MESSAGE SYSTEM HERE.
          connection.sendall(str.encode(reply)) #<<<Instead of sendall I want to just send it to a specific user in the dictionary above.
        reply = f'Server: {message}'
        connection.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    connection.close()
```

My inspiration is the /w and /party system in Valorant, which is what I'm trying to recreate (amongst other additions). I'm stuck and I need some help. Any advice?

Comment: The client can't do this, of course.  The server is the entity who owns the sockets, and the only one who knows there are multiple clients.  There has to be a way to identify clients, the server has to be able to map the client identifiers to sockets, and the protocol has to have a way for client 1 to say "send only to client 2".  How will client 1 even know that client 2 exists?

Comment: The idea is that Client 1, whose username would appear in the global chat as they speak, can actively see the username of Client 2 as the latter speaks. They would then type, for example, "/w Client 2 Hello". The code above detects the /w and (in a few hours from now) it will be able to pull "Client 2" from the string, which it would compare to the dictionary above (or whichever way it would normally identify Client 2's socket - I don't know how it would do that, hence my question). 

Also, before fully joining the chat, the client faces a UI which has the active userbase list on it.

Comment: I assume that each `client_handler` handles one client.  So, you can save the `connection` object in your dictionary.  Presumably you'll figure out the username during the start of the conversation.  You look it up in your dictionary, and use the appropriate `connection` to send.

Comment: I assume by using socket.sendto(), correct? I've never used .sendto() before, however, and I'm not entirely sure it would work that way. I'm very new to client-server code and I haven't gotten fully accustomed to the socket library.

Comment: You would use `connection.send`, EXACTLY like you have in the example above.  It's just that the `connection` object comes from your list, not as a parameter.